# split array element before . eg li.mean-array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm new to ruby i would like to know how can i split element containing special character.

I have the following array :

```
my_array = ["sh.please-word", ".things-to-do" , "#cool-stuff", "span.please-word-not"]
my_array.slice!(0..1)
puts my_array 

=>#cool-stuff
=>span.please-word
```

i want it to split array elements that doesn't start with either a dot(.) or a (#) and return the list like this:

```
.please-word
.things-to-do
#cool_stuff
.please-word-not
```

i tried to use the slice method for a string which works perfectly, but when i try with the array element it doesn't work.

this is what i have done so far.

```
list_of_selectors = []
file = File.open("my.txt") 
file.each_line do |line|
  list_of_selectors << line.split(' {')[0] if line.start_with? '.' or line.start_with? '#' 
end 
while line = file.gets
  puts line 
end
i = 0 
while i < list_of_selectors.length
  puts  "#{list_of_selectors[i]}"
  i += 1
end
list = []
list_of_selectors.each { |x| 
  list.push(x.to_s.split(' ')) 
}

list_of_selectors = list
puts list_of_selectors

list_of_selectors.map! { |e| e[/[.#].*/]}

puts list_of_selectors
```

Comment: Where does the array come from?

Comment: it comes from a file, where i created and empty array and read each line, and check if line start with a (#) hashtag or (.) dot, and iterate through the loop. after iterating i split each element where there are spaces, and add it to a new array list. after this i want to split all element that does not start with a (.)dot.  e.g li.ui-native-tabs. this should be splitted to a new array.

Answer (score 2):

```
result_array = my_array.map { |x| x[/[.#].*/] }
# => [".please-word", ".things-to-do", "#cool-stuff", ".please-word-not"]
```

The above uses a regular expression to extract the text, beginning with either a dot(`.`) or a hashtag (`#`), and return it in the resulting array.

Comment: i tried using the regular expression i still get the span.please-word-not

Comment: I've run the code as I posted it, and got the posted result. Can you show me the exact code you run?

Comment: my_array = ["sh.please-word", ".things-to-do" , "#cool-stuff", "span.please-word"]
my_array.map { |e| e[/[.#].*/ ] }
puts my_array

Comment: Oh, now I see. I've updated my answer - `my_array` does not change, the `result_array` is the truncated data. If you want to change the array itself, use `map!` instead of `map`.

Comment: now that works, with regard to my code it says it can't covert Regexp to integer. what i'm trying to achieve is that from the splitted list,i want to extract the line that does not start with a dot(.) i will paste the code below

Comment: i'm trying to past my code here it exceeds characters limit

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but try to change `list_of_selectors = list` to `list_of_selectors = list.flatten`

Comment: thanks now it works, all i wanted to was to split the returned list which does not start with a dot(.). eg. from li.mist-tabs to .mist-tabs.